# Python Flask routes other than "/" give 404s using virtualenv with nginx and uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, virtualenv, uwsgi

I have a simple Flask app that I'm trying to run behind nginx and uwsgi. Everything works as expected when I run the app with Flask's dev server. I point my browser to localhost:5000 and localhost:5000/hello and see "Hi!" and "Hello!", respectively.

But when I try running the app with uwsgi and nginx, I can see the route at "/" just fine, i.e., I see "Hi!" on localhost:8181. But I get a 404 Not Found for the "/hello" route at localhost:8181/hello. I get 404s for any route I try to add to the app that isn't just "/".

My app's folder structure looks like this:

```
my_app/
    app/
        __init__.py
    venv/
    app.py
    uwsgi.xml
```

Where `__init__.py` is simply:

```
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return 'Hello!'

@app.route('/')
def hi():
    return 'Hi!'
```

app.py is:

```
from app import app
from flask import Flask

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

uwsgi.xml:

```
<uwsgi>
    <plugin>python27</plugin>
    <socket>127.0.0.1:4141</socket>
    <master/>
    <processes>4</processes>
    <harakiri>60</harakiri>
    <reload-mercy>8</reload-mercy>
    <cpu-affinity>1</cpu-affinity>
    <stats>/tmp/stats.socket</stats>
    <max-requests>2000</max-requests>
    <limit-as>512</limit-as>
    <reload-on-as>256</reload-on-as>
    <reload-on-rss>192</reload-on-rss>
    <venv>/PATH/TO/my_app/venv</venv>
    <no-orphans/>
    <vacuum/>
    <enable-threads/>
</uwsgi>
```

and the relevant content of my nginx.conf:

```
upstream uwsgi_host4 {
    server 127.0.0.1:4141;
}

server {
    listen 8181;
    server_name localhost;
    root /PATH/TO/my_app;

    location / {
        set $app app;
        uwsgi_pass uwsgi_host4;
    }
}
```

I've been stuck on this all day and can't help but think the answer is something obvious. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

****~*~Update~*~****

Seems to be a problem with virtualenv. If I run the uwsgi command outside my virtualenv and remove the `<venv></venv>` line from uwsgi.xml, everything works. However, uwsgi says it's using Python 3.3, which is my machine's default; one reason I need to use a virtualenv is so I can use 2.7.

If I run uwsgi outside the virtualenv with the `<venv></venv>` line in the file, I get the error `ImportError: No module named 'encodings'`

If I run uwsgi after activating the virtualenv, I get the aforementioned result (404s for routes other than '\')